# Preprocessor definition cannot be identified in all project files for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, macros, dllexport

I set preprocessor definition as follows:
[image]

then Wrote the preprocessing codes in `ConfigParamsHomog.h` 
[image]

the macro `RANSAC_EXPORT` can be identified, while something different occured when rewriting above codes in `HomogEstimator.h`

[image]

why the macro cannot be identified in `HomogEstimator.h`? to my understanding, the macro should cover the whole project once it added into the preprocessor definition.

Comment: Is this a real error or just an intellisense/visual assist thing? I think I sometimes also had such visual errors, but it compiled without flaw.

Comment: I think it is a real error, because the linker will report "unresolved external symbol"  once referring to the exported lib

Comment: I have to add the definition of macro in every individual file instead.

Comment: No, that's not the way to go. You should have it defined at project level. And also you could place that whole `#ifdef` in a separate header file, and include it in any file you need it. Is *HomogEstimator.h* included by any *.c(pp)* file?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the same problem. What I did to fix the issue is make sure that the header file is getting included in the main.cpp file (the file that holds your main function). It appears global preprocessor definitions in headers won't work unless they get included into main.cpp.

Answer (score -1):

This was (sort of) asked again 2 years later at [Preprocessor definitions not working in VS2019 C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783677/preprocessor-definitions-not-working-in-vs2019-c) .
There were some good suggestions made (similar in both) but neither thread "closed out" in my opinion with a definitive answer.
I read and confirmed I had all the suggested actions done, but still no joy.

'Someone' (somewhere else, sorry, I've lost the link) suggested that VS IntelliSense may not have been working properly in this situation. Taking this to heart I defined my symbol explicitly in the header file and rebuilt the project successfully.
The next day I got messages saying that my symbol was being defined twice, so I pulled out the explicit definition and now all is working as expected! WTF?
So, all I can really suggest is fudge the definition so that the project builds successfully and maybe, maybe, the problem will "fix itself".

Not satisfactory, I know, but maybe my experience will help someone else :)