# Preprocessor definitions not working in VS2019 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2019

I have a QT 4.8 app in VisualStudio 2019 and no matter what I setup in the active configuration Preprocessor definitions, none of them seems to apply to the project.

If I go to check what should be applied to the current file, it seems to have it, but visual studio shows the #ifdef in gray and the #else active, which should not be true.

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but do you have the active "Platform" selected in that property page?

Comment: I have only the Win32 platform in the solution. So yes. And the other settings for the project do work, since i have diferent libs in the linker for debug and release. The preporcessor defintions dont want to work.

Comment: Does it work when you #define KREATOR_DEBUG just above it?

Comment: You define `KREATOR_DEBUG` for the debug configuration. Do you build your project also with the debug configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You could check that the setting of `Platform` and `Configuration` in Property Pages is the same as  the setting of `Solution Platforms` and `Solution Configurations` building the when building the project . You can refer to the following pictures:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFesy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9LFz.png)

Also, you could try to add `#define KREATOR_DEBUG` above the file. If so, you couldn't worry about the two settings are different.

Comment: They are the same. If they werent' I would not be able to have different libraries linked for debug and release. Just the preprocessor defintions do not work. #define KREATOR_DEBUG in an include file works, but I need it to be different in debug e release.

Comment: If you want to be different in debug and release, you could keep the same setting and add `KREATOR_DEBUG` in the `Preprocessor Definitions`. For example, you want to run `qDebug()` when releasing, you could set `Configuration` as `Release` and set `Platform` as `Win32` in the `Property Pages`. Also, you need to add `KREATOR_DEBUG` in the `Preprocessor Definitions` . Then, set `Solution Configuration` as `Release` and set `Solution Platform` as `X86`. If you don’t want to run `qDebug()` when debugging, you don’t need to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure KREATOR_DEBUG was defined in all your projects?

In my experience if you use

```
#ifdef KREATOR_DEBUG 
 ...
#endif
```

in a lib project's source file and the lib used in another project (dll or exe project) then KREATOR_DEBUG Preprocessor Definition should be defined both in the lib project and the other project as well.